# Python Plotting from Lists Duplicate Legend Entries

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe, plot

I have the following Dataframe:

```
Rec  Channel  Time  Value 1 
Pre             10      20
Pre             20      42
Event    A      30      39
FF              40      75
Post     A      50      11
Post     B      60      69
```

I have the following code:

```
idxall = df[df.Channel.isin(['A', 'B'])].index

Time = []
Time.append(idxall['Time'].tolist())

Value1 = []
Value1.append(idxall['Value 1'].tolist())
ln1 = ax1.plot(Time, Value1, 'kD', label = 'CHANNEL')
```

So within the list there are n number of instances and when I go to plot, there are n number of instances duplicated in my legend, is there a way to resolve this within the syntax so that there is only one label in the legend titled 'CHANNEL' and not one for every instance in the lists?  Can someone please advise?

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @DavidG please see above if that provides a little more content

Comment: Not really. A MCVE is a small piece of code that reproduces the problem that other people can run on the machines

Comment: You should be able to run that on your computer?  The dataframe is pulled in as a .csv file.